# Best practices using CRUD / REST and non-CRUD methods?

Tags: rest, laravel, crud

In an effort to push our development toward a resource-based, CRUD pattern, I'm using RESTful controllers in Laravel. However, I'm running into a need for non-standard methods in these controllers. I often need to add methods to the controllers to handle actions which don't fall into the CRUD pattern.

Does this mean I should abandon the CRUD+REST pattern altogether and pick it back up when a future project can fit into the CREATE/READ/UPDATE/DESTROY pattern? Or does the CRUD+REST pattern still assume that a project will need some non-standard methods in many instances? If so, is there a preferred way to implement them?

For example:
-- Presenting a list view of a given object in the system. Say, a list of users or list of posts.
-- OR Attaching, say, a maintenance script or command to a button.

Neither of these instances seem to correlate directly to a CRUD method.

Comment: This is really quite vague. Can you give an example of one of these non-standard methods?

Comment: Apologies. I've edited the post to include a couple of examples.